# Tapering/spreading out part of a Bevel

Tags: mesh, bevel

New to this site however have been playing around with blender for a few years on and off.

I'm in the process of making a game asset so fairly low poly model. I previously made the model before but wasnt 100% happy with the result.

I'm stuck at this stage where I want to take a bevelled curve and sort of spread out the vertices towards the lower part so the bevelled edge is not so sharp and sort of 'tapers' out.

I was able to do this in my previous model by following a tutorial but it was a long time ago and I've completely forgotten the method I used. I know it was fairly simple and it involved grabbing the said vertices and sort of spreading them out.

[image]

This is what I have so far and as you can see by my terrible painting I want to spread the lower part out but still keep it fairly even and rounded.

[image]

As you can see from my previous model above, this is the desired effect.

Has anyone got any tips or advice on how to achieve this? Its a simple concept but I just can't put my finger on the method I used before.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your problem, it looks good, you should just add some bevels to round the angles and some edge loops to avoid the ngons:

[image]

Comment: Ah yes maybe I haven't explained it clearly. But the second image is an old model of mine. I'm trying to reproduce it. like you have. How did you go about spreading out the vertices at the bottom of the bevel but still keeping it nicely rounded and in proportion? Thats my main question.

I'm trying to achieve what you did in the first part of your image.

Comment: I've just selected the bottom and S to scale

Comment: Hmm I've been trying that, but it keeps deforming the original shape but I'll give it another shot incase I'm being really stupid.

Comment: maybe enable the Proportional Editing button?